# Install SharePoint och on two disks better performance or not?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am installing a SharePoint 2013 on a Development Machine.
I have 2 disks on my virtuel drive. I have installed 1 disk with Windows Server and Sql Server and i was thinking to install SharePoint on the second disk? Will i get any better performance if i do that?

### Disk 1

SQL Server
Windows Server

### Disk 2

Sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, not likely.

Longer answer, with knowing the exact details it's difficult to give an accurate answer, however this configuration is only going to give an increase in performance if the virtual drives actually map to separate physical disks with the necessary infrastructure to prevent any other bottle necks. To make this work will take a degree of care, time, effort and hardware

tldr; it's probably not worth the effort